# Read excel file from google drive without downloading file

Tags: python, excel, google-drive-api

I wants to read **excel sheets** from excel file on google drive **without downloading** on local machine! i searched for google drive api but couldn't find solution i tried following code please need suggestion:

```
'''
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
import pandas as pd

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

file_id = 'abc'
file_name = 'abc.xlsx'  

downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id': file_id})
downloaded.GetContentFile(file_name)


class TestCase:
  def __init__(self, file_name, sheet):
    self.file_name = file_name
    self.sheet = sheet
    testcase = pd.read_excel(file_name, usecols=None, sheet_name=sheet)
    print(testcase)


class TestCaseSteps:
   def __init__(self, file_name, sheet):
    self.file_name = file_name
    self.sheet = sheet
    testcase = pd.read_excel(file_name, usecols=None, sheet_name=sheet)
    print(testcase)
```

testcases = TestCase(file_name, 'A')
steps = TestCaseSteps(file_name, 'B')
'''

Comment: And you want to do this "without downloading Python"? Or what does the title mean?
Edit: Nevermind I'm brain afk - you just but the python there to say "in Python"

Comment: actually i want to read excel file sheets (in object in python) on google drive without downloading on local machine. when i use pandas to read excel sheets i need to download file from google drive to local machine first then i can read. so,  can I read excel files directly on google drive instead downloading on local machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your goal and situation as follows.

- You want to read the XLSX downloaded from Google Drive using `pd.read_excel`.
- You want to achieve this without saving the downloaded XLSX data as a file.
- Your `gauth = GoogleAuth()` can be used for downloading the Google Spreadsheet as the XLSX format.

In this case, I would like to propose the following flow.

1. Download the Google Spreadsheet as XLSX format.

   - In this case, it directly requests to the endpoint for exporting Spreadsheet as XLSX format using `requests` library.
   - The access token is retrieved from `gauth = GoogleAuth()`.
2. The downloaded XLSX data is read with `pd.read_excel`.

   - In this case, `BytesIO` is used for reading the data.

By this flow, when the Spreadsheet is downloaded as the XLSX data, the XLSX data can be read without saving it as a file. When above flow is reflected to the script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Before you run the script, please set the Spreadsheet ID.

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
import pandas as pd
import requests
from io import BytesIO

spreadsheetId = "###"  # <--- Please set the Spreadsheet ID.

# 1. Download the Google Spreadsheet as XLSX format.
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + spreadsheetId + "/export?mimeType=application%2Fvnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
res = requests.get(url, headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + gauth.attr['credentials'].access_token})

# 2. The downloaded XLSX data is read with `pd.read_excel`.
sheet = "Sheet1"
values = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(res.content), usecols=None, sheet_name=sheet)
print(values)
```

#### References:

- [Download a Google Workspace Document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_document)
- [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

### Added:

At the following sample script, it supposes that the XLSX file is put to the Google Drive, and the XLSX file is downloaded.

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
import pandas as pd
import requests
from io import BytesIO

file_id = "###"  # <--- Please set the file ID of XLSX file.

# 1. Download the XLSX data.
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + file_id + "?alt=media"
res = requests.get(url, headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + gauth.attr['credentials'].access_token})

# 2. The downloaded XLSX data is read with `pd.read_excel`.
sheet = "Sheet1"
values = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(res.content), usecols=None, sheet_name=sheet)
print(values)
```

Comment: Thanks Your help I faced following error tried to change different ways learning from google worksheet source but couldn't figure out \n   "Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'{\n "erro'"\n i also checked enpoint request it shows this message <Response [403]>

Comment: @annonyos Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your error message, I thought that in your situation, the XLSX file is put to the Google Drive and you want to download it. So I added one more sample script for this. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize again.

Comment: @annonyos Now, I modified the endpoint for downloading the file. Could you please confirm it again? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)

Comment: A)Thanks Your help I faced following XLRD error tried to change different ways learning from google worksheet source but couldn't figure out  **bold**  'Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'{\n "erro' '   **bold**    B) I also checked enpoint request it shows this message **bold** <Response [403]> **bold**

Comment: @annonyos Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience again. I think that the reason of the error is due to that the XLSX data cannot be correctly downloaded. I had updated the endpoint of the additional script after I added the script. So could you please confirm it again? In that case, when `file_id` is the XLSX file on Google Drive, now I could confirm that the script worked. When the same error occurs, please confirm the file ID again.

Answer (score 3):

Get the link to the Excel file.
Replace the **"/edit?usp=share_link"** for **"/export?format=xlsx"**

```py
import pandas as pd

url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1py9cdXWCorKrRz7fUp0doPaOTJ2tiexB/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=107751642562197088720&rtpof=true&sd=true"
url_for_pandas = url.replace("/edit?usp=share_link", "/export?format=xlsx")
df = pd.read_excel(url_for_pandas)
print(df)
```