# reading xlsx to Pandas from Google Drive without downloading it?

Tags: python, pandas, google-drive-api

I am trying to read an xlsx file into a pandas df without downloading it but I am having issues.

I have tried read_excel while parsing the URL with sheet_id but encountered the following error that blocks me.

```
url = f"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{sheet_id}/export"
file_df = pd.read_excel(url, engine='openpyxl')
```

error:

```
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

I have a service account as authentication(should be enough) and can not wish to use a bearer token as a solution [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65482574/read-excel-file-from-google-drive-without-downloading-file) this suggests.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What you're trying to load is a google spreadsheet, not an xlsx (Excel) file. They can be read as csv. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611729/getting-google-spreadsheet-csv-into-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: No I'm trying to load an excel not a gsheet. I know my above approach is incorrect

Comment: OK. It seems you have to export it anyway. Try the code in my posted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since your spreadsheet is hosted on google, you should export it to the desired format.
Either csv:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(f"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id={sheet_id}&format=csv")
```

Or xlsx:

```
df = pd.read_excel(f"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id={sheet_id}&format=xlsx")
```

Comment: The second options results in the same error as the one I mentioned above. The first option returns a df object but it seems to be all messed up. The headers and records are what appears to be HTML.

Comment: To add to this I am sharing the file with the service account user, so auth shouldn't be the issue

Comment: did you specify `format=xlsx` at the end of the url for the second option? Regarding the messed up headers, I can't reproduce it. Maybe you can share a sample?